# Strange encoding on site request with python

Tags: python, html, character-encoding, python-requests, html-encode

I try to retrieve html code from a site using the code above

```
url = 'http://www.somesite.com'
obj = requests.get(url, timeout=60, verify=True, allow_redirects=True)
print(obj.encoding)
print(obj.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

but the result I took is a strange encoding like the below text

> \xb72\xc2\xacBD\xc3\xb70\xc2\xacAN\xc3\xb7n\xc2\xac~AA\xc3\xb7M1FX7q3K\xc2\xacAD\xc3\xb71414690200\xc2\xacAB\xc3\xb73\xc2\xacCR\xc3\xb73\xc2\xacAC\xc3\xb73\xc

Any ideas how can I decode the text?

Comment: "resp = connection_pool.request('GET', url)" what is the purpose of this line?

Comment: It was just an experiment i made with urllib3. Ignore this line i will delete it

Comment: What is your primary aim? Why do you print _encoded_ string which is of `<class 'bytes'>` type? Simply try `print(obj.text)` but ensure that `import sys; print (sys.stdout.encoding)` outputs `utf-8`.

Comment: My primary aim is to use beautiful soup to take some information. I print sys.stdout.encoding the output was UTF-8